# fit a smoothing spline using gam function

Tags: r, gam

I want to fit a smoothing spline using gam function. An attempt to plot the fitted values is resulting in an error -object$nsdf? I am wondering if that is a needed input and if so what is df referring to?  How to fix this code.

```
gam.fit=gam(y~s(disp,6)+s(hp,5)+s(wt,5), data=train.dat)
mean((test.dat$y - gam.pred)^2)  # 0.0002282536
plot(gam.fit, se=TRUE, col="blue",main="10.3f.gam")
# Error in 1:object$nsdf : argument of length 0
```

Thank you.  Sincerely, Mary A. Marion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gam()` call syntax:

```
gam.fit=gam(y~s(disp,6)+s(hp,5)+s(wt,5), data=train.dat)
```

suggests that you are using package `gam` instead of `mgcv`. However, the error you get, which complains about `object$nsdf`, is produced from `mgcv` package. **Do not load both packages into your R session at the same time!!**.

```
library(gam)
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100), x2 = rnorm(100), x3 = rnorm(100),
                  y = rnorm(100))
fit <- gam(y ~ s(x1,6) + s(x2,5) + s(x3,5), data = dat)
par(mfrow = c(1,3)); plot.gam(fit)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have not loaded mgcv unless it is coming in with something else but even then I  have reduced the code to only the essentials and I stil get the same error. My installation of R is corrupted somehow.

Comment: I have uninstalled R 3..3.0 and R 3.3.1. Having 2 versions on my system was getting things mixed up. Your code works beautifully now.  Thanks

Comment: My code is still not working.  Is the data.frame statement critical here?

Comment: Please see result of print(.packages()
+ )
 [1] "tree"      "pls"       "MASS"      "leaps"     "ISLR"      "Hmisc"    
 [7] "ggplot2"   "Formula"   "survival"  "lattice"   "gam"       "foreach"  
[13] "splines"   "devtools"  "car"       "boot"      "stats"     "graphics" 
[19] "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"   "base"     
>

Comment: I think the gam program is expecting an x or x1 x2 x3 in its parameter list. That is what you have. Unfortunately I am still getting an error when I use that.

Comment: I have tried to match your code.
      dat=as.data.frame(x1=s(disp,6),x2=s(hp,5),x3=s(wt,5),y=y)
      Error in as.data.frame(x1 = s(disp, 6), x2 = s(hp, 5), x3 = s(wt, 5),  : 
      argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: I think I should look at the binary version of this package or at least source code. I have never done that but maybe that may help.